# Sum data from same table based on another column id's

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table that looks like this

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
| ProductID |  ShopID  | Quantity |
+-----------+----------+----------+
|         1 |        1 |       10 |
|         2 |        1 |       10 |
|         3 |        1 |       15 |
|         1 |        2 |       25 |
|         4 |        1 |        5 |
|         2 |        2 |        6 |
|         4 |        3 |        7 |
+-----------+------------+--------+
```

And I need to get sum of quantity from multiple shops for single product.

For example: sum of quantity for ProductID 1 from ShopID 1 and 2.
So result for that would be 35.

Is it possible to do that in single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to group by product id

```
select sum(Quantity) as total from TableName 
where ProductID =1 and ShopID in (1,2)
group by ProductID
```

Comment: `GROUP` won't be necessary in this case since the query is limited to a single product, right?

Comment: It will work just fine in any version of MySQL (or any other RDBMS for that matter) if you select only an aggregate(s), which is the case here. Don't worry there's nothing wrong with your query it's rather a nit-picking on my part (sorry) and  style preference. The query optimizer is smart enough to produce the exact same query plans in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sum aggregate function on Quantity column and use the needed condition on productid and shopid.

```
select sum(Quantity) as Total_Quantity from YourTableName 
where ProductID = 1 and ShopID in (1,2)
```